# How to fix Python "IndexError: list index out of range" with CNN code

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to construct a [ResNet34 Encoder](https://neurohive.io/en/popular-networks/resnet/) as part of my CNN with the following function on Python 3.7.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorpack import *
from tensorpack.models import BatchNorm, BNReLU, Conv2D, MaxPooling, FixedUnPooling
from tensorpack.tfutils.summary import add_moving_summary, add_param_summary
from .utils import *
import sys

sys.path.append("..") # adds higher directory to python modules path.
try: # HACK: import beyond current level, may need to restructure
    from config import Config
except ImportError:
    assert False, 'Fail to import config.py'
def res_blk(name, l, ch, ksize, count, split=1, strides=1, freeze=False):
    ch_in = l.get_shape().as_list()
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        for i in range(0, count):
            with tf.variable_scope('block' + str(i)):  
                x = l if i == 0 else BNReLU('preact', l)
                x = Conv2D('conv1', x, ch[0], ksize[0], activation=BNReLU)
                x = Conv2D('conv2', x, ch[1], ksize[1], split=split, 
                                strides=strides if i == 0 else 1, activation=BNReLU)
                x = Conv2D('conv3', x, ch[2], ksize[2], activation=tf.identity)
                if (strides != 1 or ch_in[1] != ch[2]) and i == 0:
                    l = Conv2D('convshortcut', l, ch[2], 1, strides=strides)
                x = tf.stop_gradient(x) if freeze else x
                l = l + x
        l = BNReLU('bnlast',l)  
    return l

def encoder(i, freeze):
    d1 = Conv2D('conv0',  i, 64, 7, padding='valid', strides=1, activation=BNReLU)
    d1 = res_blk('group0', d1, [ 64,  64], [3, 3], 3, strides=1, freeze=freeze)

    d2 = res_blk('group1', d1, [128, 128], [3, 3], 4, strides=2, freeze=freeze)
    d2 = tf.stop_gradient(d2) if freeze else d2

    d3 = res_blk('group2', d2, [256, 256], [3, 3], 6, strides=2, freeze=freeze)
    d3 = tf.stop_gradient(d3) if freeze else d3

    d4 = res_blk('group3', d3, [512, 512], [3, 3], 3, strides=2, freeze=freeze)
    d4 = tf.stop_gradient(d4) if freeze else d4

    d4 = Conv2D('conv_bot',  d4, 1024, 1, padding='same')
    return [d1, d2, d3, d4]
```

Then i get the error

```
 line 67, in encoder
    d1 = res_blk('group0', d1, [ 64,  64], [3, 3], 3, strides=1, freeze=freeze)                       
  File "....", line 34, in res_blk
    x = Conv2D('conv3', x, ch[2], ksize[2], activation=tf.identity)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is the cause of this error and how can i fix it? The original code was a Resnet50 which worked fine i.e. the code would be

`d1 = res_blk('group0', d1, [ 64,  64,  256], [1, 3, 1], 3, strides=1, freeze=freeze)`

Comment: The 'ch' and 'ksize' list parameters aren't being passed three entries in your functional call to res_blk. You are passing [64, 64]  and [3, 3 , ]and so it raises an "index out of range" when entry '2' is indexed. Either remove one of the convolution layers, or add an additional entry to your lists when calling res_blk, to specify what I assume is the kernel size.

Comment: Thanks! Could you write an example code as an answer for clarity?

Comment: Just for clarity, which Conv2D are you calling, could you include your imports in the code above?

Comment: from tensorpack.models import BNReLU, Conv2D

Answer (score 0):

The key bit I found in the link you included is that "Each ResNet block is either two layers deep (used in small networks like ResNet 18, 34) or 3 layers deep (ResNet 50, 101, 152).".

The code you provided is catoring for the three layers required for ResNet 50, 101 and 152, but not accomodating the simpler two layer approach is this example, as far as I can tell.

There may be some more tweaking to do, but you should be able to just remove the final layer, similar to I have below, that would've otherwise been necessary in 50+ layer ResNet architectures.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorpack import *
from tensorpack.models import BatchNorm, BNReLU, Conv2D, MaxPooling, FixedUnPooling
from tensorpack.tfutils.summary import add_moving_summary, add_param_summary
from .utils import *
import sys

sys.path.append("..") # adds higher directory to python modules path.
try: # HACK: import beyond current level, may need to restructure
    from config import Config
except ImportError:
    assert False, 'Fail to import config.py'
def res_blk(name, l, ch, ksize, count, split=1, strides=1, freeze=False):
    ch_in = l.get_shape().as_list()
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        for i in range(0, count):
            with tf.variable_scope('block' + str(i)):  
                x = l if i == 0 else BNReLU('preact', l)
                x = Conv2D('conv1', x, ch[0], ksize[0], activation=BNReLU)
                x = Conv2D('conv2', x, ch[1], ksize[1], split=split, 
                                strides=strides if i == 0 else 1, activation=BNReLU)
                x = tf.stop_gradient(x) if freeze else x
                l = l + x
        l = BNReLU('bnlast',l)  
    return l

def encoder(i, freeze):
    d1 = Conv2D('conv0',  i, 64, 7, padding='valid', strides=1, activation=BNReLU)
    d1 = res_blk('group0', d1, [ 64,  64], [3, 3], 3, strides=1, freeze=freeze)

    d2 = res_blk('group1', d1, [128, 128], [3, 3], 4, strides=2, freeze=freeze)
    d2 = tf.stop_gradient(d2) if freeze else d2

    d3 = res_blk('group2', d2, [256, 256], [3, 3], 6, strides=2, freeze=freeze)
    d3 = tf.stop_gradient(d3) if freeze else d3

    d4 = res_blk('group3', d3, [512, 512], [3, 3], 3, strides=2, freeze=freeze)
    d4 = tf.stop_gradient(d4) if freeze else d4

    d4 = Conv2D('conv_bot',  d4, 1024, 1, padding='same')
    return [d1, d2, d3, d4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems there is a dimension problem of the layers still with this when applying res_blk `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 128 for 'tower0/group1/block0/add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [?,64,264,264], [?,128,132,132].` I guess this comes from how i've defined the input values for the encoder definition which i should change, i'll try look into it.

Comment: No problem, hopefully it was helpful :)